# Check if there's some file on a directory regardless of another directory inside - linux ksh

Tags: linux, ksh

I'm trying to check if there's any file on a directory but i need it to be independent of the fact that can or cannot be another directory inside.
I'm using:

```
if [ -n "$(ls -A /unload/ebia 2>/dev/null)" ]
then
  Exists="Yes"
else
  Exists="No"
fi

echo "is any file inside $PATH ? $Exists."
```

If there's nothing on $PATH, it say no, and if there's any file inside, it say yes (it's correct), but if i create a directory inside $PATH, it keeps answering yes instead there's no file. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use find:

```
    if [ -n "$(find /unload/ebia/ -type f)" ]
    then
      Exists="Yes"
    else
      Exists="No"
    fi
```

finds `-type f` switch only searches for files and skips directorys